# Single line if statement Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

How would one go about writing a one line if statement in objective-c? Is there a proper style for this?

I know of the ternary operator used for assignment (`int a = condition ? b : c`) but say I wanted to call a method is `if(condition){ [self methodCall]; }` the recommended way of dealing with this in one line?

In addition are there any objc style guides out there? (Think comparable to [this ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)) Coming back to a language after a while of not touching it makes me want to rethink how I style my code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The single-line ruby-style `if` and `unless` statements do not have an equivalent in Objective-C. You can either stick with blocks, or just call the method on the same line:

```
if (condition) {
    [self method];
}
```

or

```
if (condition)
    [self method];
```

or

```
if (condition) [self method];
```

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks.

Comment: Actually looks like you can shorten the ternary operator to `condition ?: [self method];` which is what I ended up using.

Comment: Keep in mind that the ternary operator used in that way is not a common Objective-C idiom and reduces readability.

Comment: Good point, luckily as of now I'm the only one touching the code base for it. ;)

Comment: @ipwnstuff Even if you are the only one, you should do it well. Forget Ruby and use Obj-C. Actually in many coding standards an `if` without bracers is frowned upon (even in some Ruby coding standards!). Trying to reduce the number of lines is a beginner error. There is nothing bad with increased number of lines if it increases code readability. Thinks like `?:` should be **never** used.

Answer (score 60):

**Ternary if statement** (if - else)

```
condition ? [self methodcall] : [self otherMethodCAll];
```

**Single method call**

```
if (condition) [self methodcall];
```

Comment: That's more an if-else scenario. Could I do that and only call one method?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need brackets...

```
if(condition) [self methodCall];
```

That's as succinct as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the only way of doing a "one-line `if` statement" in Objective-C is to put an `if` statement and its body on the same line.

Comment: Why do you ask "is this the only way" if you know that it is?

Comment: I'll clarify in my question. I was wondering if there was a way to use the ternary operator or a ruby like way to format a single line `if` statement.